# MySQL connection fast through mysql cli, but slow using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, google-cloud-platform

I have a MySQL database running on Google Cloud. It has SSL enforced, and so I use certificates and keys to connect to it:

- On the command line, I use: `mysql --ssl-ca=/path/to/server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=/path/to/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/path/to/client-key.pem --host=ip-address --user=username --password`
- With PDO, I use the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA`, `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT` and `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY` options to indicate the required files.

Both connections work fine, except that the PDO connection in PHP is very slow. The CLI method takes milliseconds to connect and execute a queries, while the PDO method takes 5-10 times longer for the same amount of connections. I tried both methods from the same machine, so it doesn't seem to be a hardware/network issue. Could PDO be causing issues here?

I'm using Laravel in case that might be relevant.

**Update: things I've tried**

- Run any other PHP script (that doesn't include a MySQL connection) on the same server: perfectly fast.
- Run a PHP script that connects to a database on 127.0.0.1 / localhost and performs a query: perfectly fast.
- Connect and query using MySQL CLI (as already mentioned in the question): perfectly fast - although hard to verify how fast so I could be imagining it.
- Connect and query though PHP/PDO from different machines using all the same settings: very slow, just like the original machine I tried it on.

So the only thing I haven't tried yet is turning off SSL/TLS. Unfortunately, I cannot do that with this instance for security reasons. Also, based on the fact that a SSL/TLS connection using the CLI is very fast, I'm concluding that it must be related to something PHP- or PDO-specific.

I'm going to do some debugging myself and will add any relevant results once I have them.

Comment: try to use an ip address for the db host instead of a domain name

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am using an IP address.

Comment: @Wouter first things first - are you positively sure it's PDO/SSL and not something else? Do you run an isolated connection example? Does it take the same time without ssl? Without connection at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I edited it into the question. Is this sufficient information?

Comment: When you see a connection take 5 to 10 seconds that often means a network timeout. Edit your question and post your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: im not sure , but maybe if you double check the PDO extension will be great ..., try to do the same thing with an other programming language (python for example) if its work faster , thats mean the problem is in your extension (php one) and you can debug to see whats is the problem , maybe a bad version, or a environnement problem (especially if you are working on docker or something) , if not ( if the connection is bad in both ) that means maybe you have a problem accessing the db from the ip (change the ip m verify your hosts, ...) , keep us updating

Comment: @MoxGeek It could be a PDO issue. I would like to track how fast the myql cli is connecting from the same machine, but have no idea how to do that. Any tips on that would be great. I did verify the IP.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn try to connect with the same code you have to an other mysql db (remote one) , that will shows you if you have an error in PDO extension or in DB itself .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opting for a Google Cloud Compute VM to host my PHP and then connect through a private IP. It appears that this is working.

I'm not sure if PDO was actually slower than the MySQL CLI anymore, it may have just seemed so.

Comment: likely it was the HTTPd configuration, which the question does not consider at all.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm running on NGINX, if that's relevant.

Comment: that would have been relevant, but shouldn't matter anymore, after the migration.